# hitting the chrome search history button

Tags: google-chrome, history

What is the URL corresponding to hitting the "Search History" button in `chrome://history` ? Is it a GET request or POST request?  What data do I send?

For example, I wanted to look up a userful question.  SO I search "stackexchange" in my history and found it very quickly.  In order to automatically request all items in my history mentioning "stackexchange" I would type `chrome://history/?q=stackexchange` ?  That doesn't work.

`tools > developer tools > network` only shows the outgoing requests from the browser nothing internal to Chrome

I also tried searching through: https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome+history?sort=votes&pageSize=15

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the add on better history. Please check the add link below for further details

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/obciceimmggglbmelaidpjlmodcebijb